# Add effects to asp:chart control

Tags: asp.net, animation, graph, charts

I am using asp:Chart to show graph. The graph is displayed when the page is loaded. I want to add effect to chart control like the bar should slowly go up from 0 to some value(depends on y value). How can I add such effect with asp:chart??

This is my code for graph in .aspx page.

```
<asp:Chart ID="DashboardGraph" runat="server" BackColor="#D3DFF0" Palette="BrightPastel"
            BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="26, 59, 105"
            ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(500,3)" Width="500px" Height="350px">
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14.25pt, style=Bold" ShadowOffset="3"
                    Text="Inventory Statistics" ForeColor="26, 59, 105">
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
          <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Docking="Right" BackColor="Transparent">
                </asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
            <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss"></BorderSkin>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="ProductName" ChartType="Column" YValueType="Int32" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">

                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid"
                    BackSecondaryColor="Transparent" BackColor="64, 165, 191, 228" ShadowColor="Transparent"
                    BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" >
                    <Area3DStyle Rotation="10" Inclination="15" WallWidth="0" />
                    <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="8" Title="Quantity" >
                        <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="8" Interval="1" TitleAlignment="Near" Title="Products">
                        <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Below is the code for to bind asp:chart with data table

```
 DataTable dtGraph = objDashboard.GetDahboardGraphData();
 DashboardGraph.DataSource = dtGraph;
 DashboardGraph.Series["ProductName"].XValueMember = "ProductName";
 DashboardGraph.Series["ProductName"].YValueMembers = "Total";

 DashboardGraph.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but asp:Chart controls do not offer any kind of animation, they are rendered images. There are plenty of products out there that you can get to create the effect you're looking for though, like [VISIfire](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_chart_videos.php) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/appearance.xml), but they use technologies like Silverlight for the animation. If you're willing to purchase them, they are relatively easy to work with.

If you look at [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2010v2/i/dxcharts-2d-bar-point-animation.swf) video from DevExpress, it seems to be doing exactly what you're asking for. And they have excellent documentation [here](http://help.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5108) for the control.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this recently, but it is client side (javascript) http://nickqizhu.github.com/dc.js/